# How to hide text in UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to create a tab bar with just the image, no title. How would I go about doing this?

Here is how I set the image:

```
FeedViewController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Describe-Home_Icon_NormalArtboard-1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[FeedViewController.tabBarItem setTitle:@""];
```

Comment: The image is still in the same position, just with the text blank.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done within the interface builder (storyboard or xibs).

Please see the attached screenshot. You can place name of your image here and simply leave the 'Default title' space blank, as I have done here.

In this way it also cuts down the need for adding unnecessary code to your project, easier to read and edit.

Hope this helps, cheers Jim.

[image: screenshot of where you can do this from utilities panel on interface builder]