# Using a UITabBar or a UIToolBar

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitoolbar

I am currently using a UITabBar, but I am having some problems. I am trying to hide the text that is normally bellow the icons in the bar as well as adding a custom action to one of the buttons, and have the rest do the default action. I was wondering if it would be better to use a UIToolbar for this, but it would be a lot of extra work. Do you have any tips on how to hide the text and add an action to one of the buttons. I can't figure out how to do these things

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394689/how-to-hide-text-in-uitabbar

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to determine when an item has been selected: 
[set up an action with a tab bar item - iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575430/set-up-an-action-with-a-tab-bar-item-iphone)

Removing a title: 
[How to move title of UITabBarItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448130/how-to-move-title-of-uitabbaritem)